# console logging data with ajax post method

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I am trying to make a post request via jquery and then console.log the data object in the callback function of the request.
client-side:

```
var save = $('<button/>',{
        class: 'btn btn-link',
        id: url,
        type: 'submit',
        value: 'Submit',
        text: 'save for later?',
        click: function(event){
            var reqData = { article : this.id};
            $.post('/profile', reqData, function(data){
                console.log(data);
            })
        }
```

server-side:

```
router.post('/profile', function(req, res) {
console.log(req.body);
// User.find();
console.log(req.user._id);
var article = new Article({article: req.body.article});


article.save(function(error, doc) {
        if (error) {
            res.send(error);
        } else {

            var id = doc._id;
            User.findOneAndUpdate({
                _id: req.user._id
            }, {$push :{
                article: id
            }}).exec(function(err, doc) {
                if (err) {
                    res.send(err);
                } else {
                   res.send(doc);
                }
            })
            res.send(doc);
        }
})
```

I keep getting the error message 'can't set headers after they are sent', and if I comment out the res.send(doc); within the .exec promise, then the data will console.log, but the page will quickly refresh and erase it.

Comment: It looks like you're calling `res.send(doc)` twice. Remove the call at the bottom. To avoid the page reloading I guess you need to call `event.preventDefault();` in your button's click handler.

Comment: You are sending the response in a promise and after it too, it's normal, you have a second send when it sent previously

Comment: event.preventDefault did the trick. I'm building an app (which for the most part works) and it has been a great refresher for jQuery and I guess event.preventDefault slipped my mind, I know this question was simple, and I'll keep in mind to ask more thoughtful questions in the future.

Answer (score -1):

The error `'can't set headers after they are sent'` means that you are trying to *respond* multiple times. The final `res.send` is being sent initially, and then once the `exec` callback's if/else is evaluated, a second `res.send` is attempted.

Comment: Ok, I see it more clearly I know the question was simple, I was just stuck with two different scenarios.